# What's cronbach's alpha and How to use this coefficient in the assessment of a learner

Tags: statistics

I meant by a coefficient called Cronbach's alpha.
I did a little research , i found the following :

> In statistics, Cronbach's  (alpha)[1] is a coefficient of internal
>   consistency.

What is the origin of this coefficient.
there are theorems or lemmas which introduced this concept?
Indeed, this coefficient met me during a search in the knowledge management in a learning platform.
I've found precisely in document that explains CBM(Confidence-Based Mark )
What is the effect of this coefficient in the assessment of a learner.

**NOTE** : System don't accept my tags(as it is new and i don't that enough reputation to create new) which is : cronbach-alpha, coefficient, assessment

Comment: let me say that i am sad to see no answer :(

Comment: there is an answer please !